# Python: Increment if a name and year appears in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am if there is an efficient way in python to increment the occurrences of the horse's name based on the year they raced?

For example, consider the dataframe:

```
|    | horse         |   year_race |
|---:|:--------------|------------:|
|  0 | Hackney       |        2012 |
|  1 | Orlov Trotter |        2016 |
|  2 | Marwari       |        2011 |
|  3 | Hackney       |        2012 |
|  4 | Marwari       |        2018 |
|  5 | Hackney       |        2015 |
|  6 | Marwari       |        2014 |
```

I would like the result to show the following:

```
{
"Hackney": 1,
"Orlov Trotter": 0
"Marwari": 2
}
```

If a horse only raced once, then let the occurrence be 0. Hackney only has an occurrence of 1 because there is a duplicate entry in 2012. Marwari has occurrences of 2 because the horse has raced 3 different years.

Is there a python way to solve this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) per `horse`, subtract `1` and convert to dictionary:

```
d = df.groupby('horse', sort=False)['year_race'].nunique().sub(1).to_dict()
print (d)
{'Hackney': 1, 'Orlov Trotter': 0, 'Marwari': 2}
```